# On finding a limit value

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the value for 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n}\ ?$$

According the answers given in the book, it should be $e$, but I can't solve it.  Can someone help me please?

Comment: Note that $$\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n = \left(1 + \frac 1n\right)^n$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left(\frac {n+1}{n}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac {1}{n}\right)^n
$$

$$=e^{  n  \ln (1+\frac {1}{n})  } $$

$$=e^{\frac {\ln (1+\frac {1}{n})}{\frac {1}{n}}} $$

but

$$\lim_{X\to 0}\frac {\ln (1+X)}{X}=1$$

thus with $X=\frac {1}{n} $,

we find that your limit is $$e^1=e $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider $$A_n=\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n\implies \log(A_n)=n\log\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)=n\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ Now, rmember that for small $x$, $\log(1+x)\sim x$; replace $x$ by $\frac 1n$ and ... continue.